# Elasticsearch include other fields in top level aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My indexed documents are as follows:

```
{
  "user": { 
     "email": "test@test.com",
     "firstName": "test",
     "lastName": "test" 
  },
  ...
  "category": "test_category"
}
```

Currently I have an aggregation which counts documents by the user's email and then a sub aggregation to count categories for each user:

```
"aggs": {
  "users": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "user.email",
      "order": {
        "_count": "desc"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "categories": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "category",
          "order": {
            "_count": "desc"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to include the user's first and last name to the buckets generated by the top aggregation, while still getting the same results from the categories sub aggregation. I've tried including the `top_hits` aggregation, but I didn't have any luck getting the results I want.

Any advice? Thanks!

EDIT:

Let me rephrase. I actually did get the desired result in terms of user data with the `top_hits` aggregation, I just don't know how to properly include it in my original aggregation so that the `categories` sub aggregation still gives me the same result. I tried the following `top_hits` aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
  "user": {
    "top_hits": {
      "size": 1,
      "_source": {
        "include": ["user"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have the user data in the top level agg buckets and then still have the aggregation by category below that.

Comment: Can you post the top_hist you tried? You used: _source: {include: ['users']} ?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: give a try at this: aggs: {
  users: {
    terms: {field: 'user.email'},
    aggs: {
      user: {
  top_hits: {
   _source: {include: ['user'], size = 1
   }
  }
 }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i right, user and firstname lastname have a bijection.

So you could retrieve them using  a customs script on these fields (and extract these buckets value on client side spliting with the "_" or wathever separator)

```
aggs: {
  users: {
    terms: {
        script: 'doc["users.email"].value + "_" + doc["users.firstName"].value + "_" + doc["users.lastName"].value'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work in my example. I used this aggregation instead of my own users aggregation.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working now. Seems to be giving me the desired results. Thanks!